# How to increment a variable if it is the first row of data table

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, datatable

i have a *data table* having several rows. I want to increment a variable say i, only if it is the *first row* of the data table. How can I do that?

```
 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {  
     address = (row["address"].ToString());
     Counter += 1;
     int count = Convert.ToInt16(Dt.Rows[i]["limit"]);

     //for the first row
     if (Counter == count)
     {
         i += 1;
     }

     // also if it is the last row  
       exit;
```

Comment: Get the first entry of the list in the datatable and add 1 to it. Something like this `list[0] += 1`

Comment: Why not switch to a for-Loop.`for(int index = 0; index < dt.Rows.Count; ++index)` and then check if the index equal 0 - your first row - and if the index equal your count - 1 you have your last row.

Comment: What if you just do `dt.Rows[0] += 1` ?

Comment: I think there is something missing in the question. I can count the number of first rows in a DataTable much faster than that. It's 1. Always (Except if the DataTable is empty, of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should work with a for loop - hat makes the index access easier

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string address = dt.Rows[i].Field<string>("address");
    if (i == 0)
    {
        //first row, increment here
    }
    if (i == dt.Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        //last row
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not a simple *flag*, say `isFirstRow`?

```
 bool isFirstRow = true;

 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {  
     if (isFirstRow) 
     {
         isFirstRow = false;

         //TODO: Increment here 
     } 
     ...
```

**Edit:** In case of *last row* we can do postprocessing:

```
 DataRow lastRow = null;

 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
   // Candidate for the last row
   lastRow = row;
   ... 
 }

 if (lastRow != null) {
   //TODO: Put relevant code for the last row     
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like below. Use `IndexOf` method of DataRowCollection class to determine if it's the first row. I have created  a sample DataTable object before the loop. The main part of this answer is the if statement within the loop's body that checks for row index.

Keep in mind that the index of row in DataTable starts from 0 and not 1. So, first row has an index of 0, second row has an index of 1, third row row has index of 2 and so on.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("EmployeeId", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Grade", typeof(int));

    // Here we add five DataRows.
    dt.Rows.Add(11, "John", "Smith", 9);
    dt.Rows.Add(92, "Sunita", "Mali", 7);
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Anil", "Kumar", 4);
    dt.Rows.Add(5, "Mike", "Reb", 11);
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "Sunil", "Dev", 12);

   //your counter variable
    int i= 0;

    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
      //use IndexOf method to check if it's the first row
      if( dt.Rows.IndexOf(row) == 0) {
        i++;//only first row causes increment of i
      }

      if(dt.Rows.IndexOf(row) == (dt.Rows.Count -1)) {
       //its the last row of datatable
      }

    }
```

Comment: and for the last row?

Comment: I will just add that in a moment.

Comment: The last row index will always be one less than the total count since the index starts from 0 and not 1.